# Power BI matrix conditional formatting by columns values

Tags: powerbi

I have a matrix visual which has date columns. What I would like to do is to change formatting of the values for specific date columns. Specifically, I would like to change the background color for my date columns from the latest Monday to the Monday a week before (i.e., corresponding to from 10/16/2023 to 10/9/2023). Data is fetched daily and is added to the existing data. I always need to find the period from the latest Monday and to the Monday a week before.

[image]

Would somebody kindly advise how I can achieve this? Using DAX is a bit overwhelming but that might be good. I can produce an external csv file that gives dates to be highlighted so a solution that uses an external file is good too.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved. If I try an external file with Date and IsHighlighted flag with 1 or 0 (not True or False), it works well with matrix conditional formatting. Thanks!

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.